# Call to a member function on a non-object , Undefined variable: login

Tags: php

Ive been trying to get this to work all day but it doesnt seem to work. The $login variable was called but it doesnt affect the if statement:

```
  $login = new Login();

  function inclu(){
    if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true){ 

       include (($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/log/assets/displayuser.php"));
     } 
     else {
      // the user is not logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
     // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are not logged in" view.
     include (($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/log/assets/displaysign.php"));
        }; 
    }
```

It comes up with the errors:
Notice: Undefined variable: login in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\log\index.php on line 38

Fatal error: Call to a member function isUserLoggedIn() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\log\index.php on line

Comment: You need to learn basic PHP scoping rules. `$login` doesn't exist in your `inclu()` function. Read and learn: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare $login again in the function:

```
function inclu() { global $login; /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

the first line in the inclu function must be 'global $login;' to get the global variable login accessible inside the function. it's a special scoping technique of PHP